# Django : fixtures object not retrievable

Tags: python, django, testing, fixtures

I didn't see anywhere that LiveServerTestCase wasn't loading fixtures, but when i execute the following :

```
class FrontTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    fixtures = ['event.json']


    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        print(Event.objects.all())
```

The output is :

```
Using existing test database for alias 'default'...
[]
```

While when i use `TestCase`

```
class FrontTest(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['event.json']


    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        print(Event.objects.all())
```

The ouput is :

```
[<Event: event search>]
```

Do you know why my fixture is loaded only in TestCase ? I'd really like to make it work to use Selenium. Thanks !

PS : `event.json :`

```
{
       "model": "mezzanine_agenda.event",
       "pk": 1,
       "fields": {
          "comments_count": 0,
          "keywords_string": "",
          "rating_count": 0,
          "rating_sum": 0,
          "rating_average": 0.0,
          "site": 1,
          "title": "event search",
          "slug": "event-search",
          "_meta_title": "",
          "description": "event search",
          "gen_description": true,
          "created": "2018-05-25T15:49:55.223Z",
          "updated": "2018-05-25T15:49:55.257Z",
          "status": 2,
          "publish_date": "2018-05-25T15:49:32Z",
          "expiry_date": null,
       }
    },
```

Comment: What's your directory structure here?

Comment: Do you get any other messages (the testcase that for instance complains that the fixture can not be found)?

Comment: No, my fixture is loaded because if i change the "title" field and load my test, have the following output : `Event has no field named 'titles'`

Comment: Could it be because of `LiveServerTestCase` ?

Comment: I don't suppose you're using SQLite as your database for the tests are you?

Comment: I'm using postgre !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `TransactionTestCase` loads fixtures in instance' `setUp` method, so its child classes including `LiveServerTestCase` do the same - except `TestCase`, which uses single atomic transaction per class and loads the fixtures in `setUpClass` to speed up the test execution. This behaviour was added in [#20392](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20392).

What it means for you is that you should move all database related code from `setupClass` to `setUp` in the `LiveServerTestCase` child classes:

```
class FrontendLiveTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # the transaction is opened, fixtures are loaded
        assert Event.objects.exists()
```

#### Note

In case you'd try mixing up the `TestCase`s atomic transactions with `LiveServerTestCase`s background threads: as stated in `LiveServerTestCase` docs,

> It inherits from `TransactionTestCase` instead of `TestCase` because the threads don't share the same transactions (unless if using in-memory `sqlite`) and each thread needs to commit all their transactions so that the other thread can see the changes.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Tried everything but that ! Thank you also for teaching me the `exists` method !

Comment: Nice, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, and sadly, Django ignores fixtures that it does not find. The error you are seeing means that Django could not locate the fixture file and fails with a warning: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18990

Here's how Django finds fixtures:

- Using absolute paths to the fixture files, not a good idea since the fixture is probably placed as part of code -> this will override the second technique
- It looks under all directories defined under `settings.FIXTURE_DIRS`
- It looks under all **app directories** inside a folder called `fixtures` by convention.

Based on this, see where your file is located, and you can get a fix on this issue

Here's the Django code for `fixture_dirs`:

```
@cached_property
def fixture_dirs(self):
    """
    Return a list of fixture directories.

    The list contains the 'fixtures' subdirectory of each installed
    application, if it exists, the directories in FIXTURE_DIRS, and the
    current directory.
    """
    dirs = []
    fixture_dirs = settings.FIXTURE_DIRS
    if len(fixture_dirs) != len(set(fixture_dirs)):
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.FIXTURE_DIRS contains duplicates.")
    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
        app_label = app_config.label
        app_dir = os.path.join(app_config.path, 'fixtures')
        if app_dir in fixture_dirs:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "'%s' is a default fixture directory for the '%s' app "
                "and cannot be listed in settings.FIXTURE_DIRS." % (app_dir, app_label)
            )

        if self.app_label and app_label != self.app_label:
            continue
        if os.path.isdir(app_dir):
            dirs.append(app_dir)
    dirs.extend(list(fixture_dirs))
    dirs.append('')
    dirs = [upath(os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(d))) for d in dirs]
    return dirs
```

Comment: My fixture is found because when i change a field i've a  `Problem installing fixture` while testing.